# Xamarin.Forms - My ControlTemplate doesn't respect HeightRequest

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created a BottomBar in my App.xaml and I am using ControlTemplate to call it into the Xaml file of a different page.

My problem is: I have tried using HeightRequest inside the Layout in my App.xaml file, also tried using it in the Xaml file of the other page when calling it, and nothing seems to work. The page doesn't respect the HeightRequest.

I want them all to have the same height on every page (60).

[page1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SDA4.png)

[page2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETC5O.png)

[page3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEBaG.png)

As you can see, the bottom bar has a different size on each page.

My App.xaml:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="CartTemplate" >
            <AbsoluteLayout
                x:Name="CartSection"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                BackgroundColor="#004EFF"
                HeightRequest="60">
                <Image Source="caricon"
                       HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                       AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5"
                       AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"/>
                <Grid 
                    HeightRequest="22"
                    IsVisible="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.OrderCountVisible}"
                    WidthRequest="22"
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                    Padding="25,0,0,10">
                    <Ellipse Fill="White"/>
                    <Label
                        Text="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.cartNumberItems}"
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        TextColor="#004EFF"
                        FontAttributes="Bold"
                        FontSize="14"
                        Padding="0,0,0,3"
                        FontFamily="{StaticResource Helvetica}"/>
                </Grid>
                <AbsoluteLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.CarCommand}" />
                </AbsoluteLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            </AbsoluteLayout>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

This is how I am calling the Template (At the bottom just above the end tags):

```
<TemplatedView ControlTemplate="{StaticResource CartTemplate}"/>

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you try to set the height with the Converter to connect with the screen size? Could you provide the xaml of the pages which show the different size of CartTemplate for me to test?

Comment: Hey, I shouldn't need to use a Converter here because all I want is for the Bar to have a simple height of 60. To test, add 1 element with large 2000 HeightRequest for example above the bottomBar.It will squeeze the bar like shown in the images I displayed above.

Comment: But in your code, i could not make sure what cause the HeightRequest does not work. I need more details.